# Is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that $x=x(y,z)$, $y=y(z,x)$ and $z=z(x,y)$.

Do we have that 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
or it's false ? Moreover, I don't understand why
$$\frac{\partial x(y,z)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(z,x)}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}=-1.$$

Comment: @idm: That's very ill posed problem. You did nothing say about
the functions itself. Only about dependencies on variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $z=xy$, then $x=\dfrac zy$ and $y=\dfrac zx$.

Then

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=-\frac z{y^2}\ne\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac1yx.$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the last question though? It seems the second statement is true. How is it negative one?

Comment: @idm You can see your first statement doesn't hold with a simple linear example like x = 5y + 2z

Comment: "It seems the second statement is true": are you so sure ?

Comment: You did not disprove it in your answer if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Only a special case where $z$ is given. That's clearly true, but not in general.

Comment: @Frieder: can't make sense of your comment. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: So you give for $z$ an explicit definition. Everybody knows $z=xy$. In a more general case, we may not assume
a special form for $z$, and the problem is formulated in an abstract case. We know dependencies on variables only. That's all. What the functions really do, is not clear.

Comment: @Frieder: a single counter-example is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you are differentiating implicit functions, subject to some equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ that you haven't told us about.

If you treat $x$ as a function of $y$ and $z$, and hold $z$ constant, you get
$${\partial f\over\partial x}{\partial x\over\partial y}=-{\partial f\over\partial y}$$

Do this a few times, varying the roles of $x$, $y$ and $z$.  Then the product of all the left-hand-sides is equal to the product of all the right-hand sides, from which you can derive the final relation you asked about.

But:  This is a really sloppy way to do it, because $x$ stands both for a variable and an implicit function of $y$ and $z$, etc.  Much better to let one symbol stand for one thing, as per Frieder's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is true by the [implicit function theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275610/proof-and-uses-of-implicit-function-theorem).

If the second statement is true then the first statement is false. Proof:

Suppose $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$.

Then $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 1$$, contradicting the second statement.

Answer (score 1):

The following I find reassuring as it explicit in what exactly is held constant. If we have a function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ with the $x_i$ restricted so that $f=0$, then

$$\frac{\partial f(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial x_i}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i+2},...,x_n}$$
$$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, x_{i+2},...,x_n}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i+1}}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i}, x_{i+2},...,x_n}\cdot \frac{\partial x_{i+1}}{\partial x_i}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i+2},...,x_n}  .$$

But because $f=0$, this is $0$, and so

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial x_{i+1}}{\partial x_i}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i+2},...,x_n}= \prod_{i=1}^n-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, x_{i+2},...,x_n} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i+1}}\mid_{x_1,...,x_{i-1}, x_{i}, x_{i+2},...,x_n} \right)^{-1}=(-1)^n.$$