# Total derivative of transcendental function as a ratio of its partial derivatives

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

I have come across following:

$$\frac{dI_{(V)}}{dV} = - \frac{\frac{\partial f_{(V,I)}}{\partial V}}{\frac{\partial f_{(V,I)}}{\partial I}}$$

where:

- $I_{(V)}$ is transcendental function (a function with both $I$ and $V$ as variables)
- and $f_{(V,I)} = I_{(V)} - I = 0$, which is often used for instance in Newton-Raphson method.

I can provide the transcendental function in question:

$$I = I_{ph} - I_s(exp\left(\frac{V+IR_s}{v_T}\right)-1)-\frac{V+IR_s}{R_{sh}}-a(V+IR_s)\left(1-\frac{V+IR_s}{V_{Br}}\right)^{-n}$$

and for completeness, the $f_{(V,I)}$ is then:

\begin{align}
f_{(V,I)} & = I_{ph} - I_s(exp\left(\frac{V+IR_s}{v_T}\right)-1)-\frac{V+IR_s}{R_{sh}}-a(V+IR_s)\left(1-\frac{V+IR_s}{V_{Br}}\right)^{-n} - I \\ & = 0
\end{align}

---

**QUESTION**:

Why the total derivative $\frac{dI_{(V)}}{dV}$ equals to ratio of partial derivatives $- \frac{\frac{\partial f_{(V,I)}}{\partial V}}{\frac{\partial f_{(V,I)}}{\partial I}}$ ?

How do I show this holds in general case ?

Comment: This is simply a statement of the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275610/proof-and-uses-of-implicit-function-theorem)

Comment: @NinadMunshi Perfect, I didnt know / didn't remember the theorem, thanks